# Why is my CASE expression non-deterministic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, calculated-columns, persisted-column

I am trying to create a persisted computed column using CASE expression:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Calendar ADD PreviousDate AS 
case WHEN [Date]>'20100101' THEN  [Date]
    ELSE NULL
    END PERSISTED
```

MSDN clearly says that CASE is deterministic, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187786%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

However, I am getting an error:

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Computed column 'PreviousDate' in
>   table 'Calendar' cannot be persisted
>   because the column is
>   non-deterministic.

Of course, i can create a scalar UDF and explicitly declare it as deterministic, but is there a simpler way around this? I am already in the middle of getting the latest service pack. Thanks.

Comment: Old question, I know, but how do you propose to *"create a scalar UDF and explicitly declare it as deterministic"* in SQL Server.  I'm told you can do so in Oracle, but I've never seen a way in SQL Server...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to [CONVERT '20100101' with a style.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx)

> Source or target type is datetime or
>   smalldatetime, the other source or
>   target type is a character string, and
>   a nondeterministic style is specified.

So, try this:

```
...WHEN [Date] > CONVERT(datetime, '20100101', 112)....
```

Date parsing from string can be unreliable as [I've answered before (mostly in comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string)

Edit:

I wouldn't say it's a bug, but SQL Server asking for 100% clarification. yyyymmdd is not ISO and SQL Server parsing yyyy-mm-dd is unreliable (see my answer link)

Answer (score 6):

Apparently it is very picky about data types. Try doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Calendar ADD PreviousDate AS 
case WHEN [Date ]> Convert(DateTime, '20100101', 101) THEN  [Date]
    ELSE Convert(DateTime, NULL, 101)
    END PERSISTED
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot mark both replies as answers, so I marked only the first one, and upvoted yours. Thanks!