# Problem with creating Indexed View AND Group BY in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, view, windows-server-2008-r2, indexed

I want to create indexed view with such t-sql:

```
    Select
   Table1_ID,
   cast(CONVERT(varchar(8),
   t2.Object_CreationDate, 112)AS DateTime) as Object_CreationDate ,
   Count_BIG(*) as ObjectTotalCount 
   from
       [dbo].Table2 t2 inner join [dbo].Table1 t1 on ...   
   Group BY
       Table1_ID, CONVERT(varchar(8), t2.Object_CreationDate, 112))
```

I need to make *group by* only by *datepart* of column `Object_CreationDate` (type  *datetime2* ).

Also I want to set index on columns `Theme_Id` AND  `Object_CreationDate` in the derived view.
If I use `cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), m.Mention_CreationDate, 112)AS DateTime)` in SELECT - I'll get problems with index on this column. Because this column (`Object_CreationDate`) is not deterministic.

I wonder if it is possible to solve a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace ...

```
CONVERT(varchar(8), t2.Object_CreationDate, 112))
```

... with

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, t2.Object_CreationDate), 0)
--OR
CAST(t2.Object_CreationDate AS date)
```

The 2nd format is SQL Server 2008+ only, the 1st is more general

This removes the time component from a datetime value in the date/datetime datatype domain without any intermediate locale dependent datetime formats

See these answers: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596663/why-is-my-case-expression-non-deterministic/3596685#3596685) and [Two(comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string)

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But when I try to set index with command create unique index IX_Theme_ID_Object_CreationDate on [View](Theme_ID,Object_CreationDate) - sql give an error that because of i don't have unique clustered index on this view, i can't add this index.

Comment: You need to identify a "unique clustered index" exactly as the error message says. perhaps "Table1_ID". How else will SQL Server know what row is what if there is no unique key for the indexed viw?