# Deterministic non-nullable truncate function for datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I was looking for a deterministic truncate function for datetime and this one did the job:

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0)
```

But this is supposed to be the input to a persisted computed column which will be a part of the primary key, so it has to be non-nullable. So I made this:

```
ISNULL(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0), '01.01.1900')
```

But now the expression became non-deterministic. Can anyone tell me why, and how I can make it deterministic?

Thanks!

Comment: @Andriy M's answer is correct and before mine. You should accept that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`01.01.1900` isn't deterministic...

This is:

```
ISNULL(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0), CONVERT(datetime, '19001010', 112)))
```

or this

```
ISNULL(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fooDT), 0), 0)
```

For more, see [Why is my CASE expression non-deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3596663/27535) which leads to [best way to convert and validate a date string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1138142/27535)

Answer (score 4):

```
ISNULL(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0), 0)
```

That is, my guess is the non-deterministic part is `'01.01.1900'`, because it depends on the locale settings.

Comment: @gbn, Martin Smith, JNK: Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string constant, use some arbitrary number instead of '01.01.1900'