# SQL Query doing strange thing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

If I run this query on SQL Server Express 2008 :

```
Insert NoteBook (Date, Note) Values ('11/04/2011 11:02:46', 'test')
```

It stored the date as 04/11/2011

How can I prevent this?

Comment: @marc_s this should be an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: This has been done to death already, not least here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx): `YYYYMMDD` (or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`) - it works always, regardless of your SQL Server language and locale settings.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NoteBook(Date, Note) 
VALUES('2011-04-11T11:02:46', 'test')
```

The date in SQL Server is **NOT** stored in any particular string-oriented format - a date is a date is a date, regardless of what you see.

You see a string representation of the date - but again: it's **NOT** stored that way - and thus you cannot "prevent" it from being stored that way...

Check your language settings in SQL Server:

```
SELECT @@LANGUAGE
```

What language do you have?? The language defines the default format in which dates are shown.

Comment: US English.  Where can I change it, or should I change it if Im going to use yyyymmdd?

Comment: @teadrinkinggeek: if you use `yyyymmdd` you don't need to change anything - that ISO-8601 format **always** works. Otherwise, you need to look at [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189491.aspx) in SQL Server - this allows you to define whether your strings will be interpreted as `MM/DD/YYYY` (for the US) or `DD/MM/YYYY` ([for pretty much the rest of the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country))

Comment: You're right!  I used INSERT INTO dbo.NoteBook(Date, Note) 
VALUES('2011-04-11T11:02:46', 'test') and it showed it correctly.  Thanks.