# not able to fetch record for string as a date type variable in sql 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

my problem is:
If i run this it returns the result

```
declare @dummy DATETIME
set @dummy ='10-20-2008'

SELECT * FROM associate WHERE dateofbirth = @dummy
```

But if I remove the quotes of the dummy var value then it returns null.

```
declare @dummy DATETIME
set @dummy =10-20-2008

SELECT * FROM associate WHERE dateofbirth = @dummy
```

Comment: It would really help if you could be a bit more clear on what the issue is.  I assumed it was that you wondered why you needed quotes around your date.  However, it is very helpful if you put your problem down in a sentence before explaining it.  For example, "I don't know why the following has to be true: my dates seem to need to be wrapped in quotes" or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005 when using dates only, [the only safe datetime string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string) is yyyymmdd. And they must be delimited in single quotes too

So you have to use `set @dummy ='20081020'`

Example:

```
set language british
declare @dummy DATETIME
set @dummy ='10-20-2008' --fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Without quotes means that expression is bigint.In your second example @dummy=10-20-2018=-2018. That means that your date will be 2018 days sooner than 01-01-1900 (23-06-1894). If you run query:

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY,'01-01-1900',@dummy)
```

You will get -2018

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended.  You need to enclose a date with quotes if you are going to write it out like that.  You could also build a date using one of the SQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

> ** USE THIS**
>
> Convert both the comparabilities to
>   VARCHAR and then compare it
>
> convert(vrachar(12),@dummy,101) = convert (varchar(12),'04/10/2008',101)