# Between older than 30 days and less than 90days

Tags: sql-server-2008, datediff, getdate

I need to return records where there is a date older than 30days but less than 90days. so If someone bought something either 31 days ago or 89 days ago its those rows i need to return, ignoring the last 30 days and anything outside of 90days.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939954/sql-server-between-two-datetime-fields-not-working-correctly. It is possibly that you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE DateCol < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,-30, GetDate())), 0)
AND   DateCol > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(dd,-90, GetDate())), 0)
```

The [`DATEADD-DATEDIFF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server) truncates the time part, so that 30 days ago means midnight 30 days ago.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20527)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(now(),date)>30 and DATEDIFF(now(),date)<90
```