# Storing SQL Server 2005 datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a php script inserting values in to SQL Server 2005 table via SQL

```
$date = '15 Jun 2011 00:00';
$sql = "INSERT INTO shows ( DateStart ) VALUES ( '$date')";
```

I have 2 issues:

1) how best to convert this date into something SQL Server understands? The default format is mm/dd/yyyy on my system but I want to present the dates as readable to the user.

2) When inserting an empty string the DateStart value gets set to 1/1/1900. How best to convert an "invalid" date into a NULL (the column already accepts NULLs) so that if `$date = ""` then `DateStart IS NULL`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Point 1: Use ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` 
  Note: For date only use `YYYYMMDD` becuase of anomalies in how SQL Server parse dates
- Point 2: `NULLIF(value, '')`

Comment: @Mark S. Rasmussen: in the comment bunfight here to both answers (was me and @marc_s) with further links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the datetime format while inserting the record in datetime column should always "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" [Default Format](http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/tools/archive/2007/05/08/what-is-the-default-datetime-format-in-sql-server.aspx)
2. gbn already told.

Comment: The linked article doesn't seem to contain any recommendations on using the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string/1138203#1138203), as it shows clearly when this format is not reliable.

Comment: Thank You Andriy. That's the reason for 81.9K reputation of gbn. I was inserting the record in database for datetime column and it stored it without T

Comment: It displays `datetime` values without `T`, yes. That's very misleading. It's great there are sites like SO where you can learn such things.