# How to check whether (var)char is a valid ISO date (112)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a char(8) field which `should` really contain a value in a yyyymmdd dateformat. 
Given a (hypothetical) table `id(int)|datestring(char(8))` I would like to be able to do something like

```
SELECT id, isValidDate(datestring) FROM my_hypothetical_table
```

It's important for me that this can be run like so as a query (so I could, for example, `SELECT * from othertable INNER JOIN hypothetical_table on hypothetical_table.id = othertable.hypothetical_FK WHERE isValidDate(hypothetical_table.datestring) = 1`). Catching errors doesn't seem viable.

Note that the IsDate() function only works with slash delimited dates, and not yyyymmdd formats.

Comment: Why on earth do you think ISDATE() only works with slash-delimited dates??? And why on earth are you storing a date in a CHAR(8) column?

Comment: yyyymmdd is the only safe date format for SQL Server. Read the comments to the 2 answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1138142/27535

Comment: I mistakenly thought so because all the exmples listed on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347(v=SQL.100).aspx use the format. Showing how to order your m/d/y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to add a check for length if you are unsure about all values being 8 digits in length.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (id INT, datestring CHAR(8))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1, '20110711')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2, '2011')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (3, '20110228')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (4, '20110229')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (5, '2011071')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (6, '201107')
SELECT id, datestring, ISDATE(datestring) AS IsDate FROM @MyTable
```

Running this produces the output:

```
id          datestring IsDate
----------- ---------- -----------
1           20110711   1
2           2011       1
3           20110228   1
4           20110229   0
5           2011071    0
6           201107     1
```

Answer (score 5):

ISDATE() will work with YYYYMMDD format too

```
SELECT ISDATE('20010101')
```