# Correct way of setting datetime value to a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to convert and validate a date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string)

While assigning a datetime value to a datetime variable in SQL Server, which format is the best to adopt for culture agnostic reasons and why?

The date intended below is 01-Dec-2013

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME
SET @myDate = '2013-12-01'
SET @myDate = '20131201'
SET @myDate = '12/01/2013'
SET @myDate = '2013-12-01T00:00:00.000'
SET @myDate = '2013-12-01T00:00:00'
```

If @myDate is of type `DATETIME2`, would your answer be different?

Answer (score 15):

Based on the [ISO 8601](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) standard, the following 3 formats in the question are valid:

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME
SET @myDate = '20131201'
SET @myDate = '2013-12-01T00:00:00.000'
SET @myDate = '2013-12-01T00:00:00'
```

> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an
>   international standard. Also, datetime values that are specified by
>   using this format are unambiguous. Also, this format is not affected
>   by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE settings.

Comment: does not work when `(SELECT r.date_format FROM master.sys.dm_exec_requests r WHERE r.session_id = @@SPID)` returns **`dmy`**

Answer (score 3):

This has been covered before e.g. [best way to convert and validate a date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138142/best-way-to-convert-and-validate-a-date-string#1138172)

> ISO-8601 format is YYYYMMDD for just dates, or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss for
>   date with time

If you can't guarantee ISO format, then you should set the applicable [DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) beforehand

**Edit**

Re : Would you still use this for `datetime2`

Yes, in fact this is clearly stated in MSDN [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx#sectionToggle1) Because of the additional precision to 100ns, ISO 8601 format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]`

Answer (score -2):

`SET @myDate = '2013-12-01T00:00:00.000'`

`SET @myDate = '2013-12-01T00:00:00'`

`SET @myDate = '2013-12-01'`

Those are the correct formats according to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Actually - if your variable is of `DATETIME` and you want to set the date only - the really proper format is `SET @myDate = '20131201'` - your last assignment is **not safe** under European language settings - it will fail....