# convert string to datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a column of dates with no delimiters. The column is nvarchar. The strings are consistent in length and format of `MMDDYYYY`. How can I convert these values to `datetime`?

edit - this question is in reference to sql server.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) and what have you searched?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert varchar into datetime in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server) and [SQL Server convert string to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135746/sql-server-convert-string-to-datetime) and [SQL Server Convert Varchar to Datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247050/sql-server-convert-varchar-to-datetime) and many others

Comment: Have you tried `cast(column as datetime)`?

Comment: I checked the suggestions first to avoid adding a duplicate comment. I have tried simply changing the column to datetime in desiger, which erases the data, and I've tried importing as datetime, which results in the data not being imported for that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(10)
SET @A = '11302012'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@A,2) + '/' + 
       SUBSTRING(@A,3,2) + '/' + RIGHT(@A,4),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @d DATETIME
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(32)
SET @s = N'12012013'
SET @d = SUBSTRING(@s, 5,4) + SUBSTRING(@s, 1,2) + SUBSTRING(@s, 3,2)
SELECT @d
END
```

You just have to mangle the string into a format SQL server can parse correctly into a date. In the above it's the YYYYMMDD format.

**EDIT** Removed "-"'s because French language settings break them.

Comment: This is a lot of work when you can just use `CONVERT`

Comment: @njk - There isn't a CONVERT style for the mmddyyyy format, unless I'm missing something http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @LastCoder And wich one is it?

Comment: @Lamak - You're going to have to elaborate a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I read your comment as *There **is** a `CONVERT` style*

Comment: The `YYYY-MM-DD` format [isn't safe](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) for implicit conversion to `datetime`. On the other hand, `YYYYMMDD` is, and so you could simplify your code down to just two SUBSTRING calls: `SUBSTRING(@s, 5, 4) + SUBSTRING(@s, 1, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

First change the format to the one that always works no matter what server settings (YYYYMMDD) using two simple string functions, then convert to datetime:

```
declare @datestring varchar(8) = '11302012';

select CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT(@datestring, 4) + LEFT(@datestring, 4)) ConvertedDatetime;
```