# Convert data to save in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I can save those information when SQL Server table column datatype is `nvarchar(MAX)` but I need to save data with another data types.

This is my database and I need to save data in to the table, but I cannot use my code do do it, but I can save in to the database using `nvarchar(MAX)` data format

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FLfH.jpg)

```
    protected void btnSaave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var dtDealerCode = txtIDealerCode.Text;
                    var dtInvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNumber.Text;
                    var dtInvoiceDate = txtInvoiceDate.Text;
                    var dtItemIdentityCode = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ItemCode");
                    var dtPurchasingPrice = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("UnitPrice");
                    var dtDiscountRate = txtDiscount.Text;
                    var dtDiscount = txtProductDiscount.Text;
                    var dtIssueMode = ddlIssueMode.SelectedValue;
                    var dtQty = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Quantity");
                    var dtTotal = (Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("GetTotal");
                    var dtExpireDate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("ExpiaryDate");
                    var dtBatchNumber = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Batch");
                    var dtUploadedStatus = txtInvoiceDate.Text;
                    var dtInsertedDate = "1";
                    var dtUploadedDate = txtInvoiceDate.Text;
                    var dtForce = txtForce.Text;
                    var dtPrinciple = txtPrinciple.Text;
                    var NewTotal = (Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("GetQuantity");
                    // (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("Total");
                    //(Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("Product")
                    sc.Add(dtDealerCode + "," + dtInvoiceNo + "," + dtInvoiceDate + "," + dtItemIdentityCode.Text + "," + dtPurchasingPrice.Text + "," + dtDiscountRate + "," + dtDiscount + "," + dtIssueMode + "," + dtQty.Text + "," + dtTotal.Text + "," + dtExpireDate + "," + dtBatchNumber.Text + "," + dtUploadedStatus + "," + dtInsertedDate + "," + dtUploadedDate + "," + dtForce + "," + dtPrinciple + "," + dtPrinciple + "," + NewTotal.Text);
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                InsertRec(sc);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using this part to save in to databaseas,

I need to save data in to the table, but I cannot use my code do do it, but I can save in to the database using `nvarchar(MAX)` data format

```
private void InsertRec(StringCollection sc)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        var splitItems = (string[])null;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
            const string sqlStatement =
                "INSERT INTO DEL_PurchasesLines1 (DealerCode,InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,ItemIdentityCode,PurchasingPrice,DiscountRate,Discount,IssueMode,Qty,Total,ExpireDate,BatchNumber,UploadedStatus,InsertedDate,UploadedDate,Force,Principle,NewTotal) VALUES";

            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3], splitItems[4], splitItems[5], splitItems[6], splitItems[7], splitItems[8], splitItems[9], splitItems[10], splitItems[11], splitItems[12], splitItems[13], splitItems[14], splitItems[15], splitItems[16], splitItems[17]);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i save in to table with data type nvarchar(MAX) , i can take message from this point



Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);



but when i change the data type in the table (http://i.stack.imgur.com/8FLfH.jpg), output is 
string msg = "Insert Error:";

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace along with your question..

Comment: i can use this table to save my data using that code.
[Table 1](http://i.imgur.com/nVwsmWT.jpg)

but i cannot save to this table
[Table 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8FLfH.jpg)

i know their is a problem with data types .. so how to fix it in my code

Comment: Some value is exceeding its limit in table 2..IF you paste your stack trace then we can identify that column..

Comment: Additional information: Insert Error:The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Yep,the only thing is date column datatype..Try replacing it with datetime.

Comment: already Column data type is datetime in the [Table 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8FLfH.jpg) ,, but output from my code is not date time format it is varchar so how to change it in code,

please help me ..

Comment: you should create a method,pass the varchar value to that method,convert it to datetime ,then insert..

Comment: can you helo me to do it ,,  with small sample with this code... some modification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653859/convert-string-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: I have posted the method as answer..

Comment: @dilan3gb Please let us know the format of `InsertedDate` which you needed to change, I mean show us Nvarchar datetime format .

Comment: one advice try to use parameterized query, this insert query of yours is very error prone .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply convert.ToDateTime at the time you are fetching data from `Datatable` , However i don't feel you need to do all this split functions to fetch values for your `Insert` query you can directly apply the `stringCollection sc` string to values field in your insert query no transformation needed to done here .

```
sc.Add(dtDealerCode + "," + dtInvoiceNo + "," + Convert.ToDateTime(dtInvoiceDate) + "," + dtItemIdentityCode.Text + "," + dtPurchasingPrice.Text + "," + dtDiscountRate + "," + dtDiscount + "," + Convert.ToDateTime(dtIssueMode) + "," + dtQty.Text + "," + dtTotal.Text + "," + Convert.ToDateTime(dtExpireDate) + "," + dtBatchNumber.Text + "," + dtUploadedStatus + "," + dtInsertedDate + "," + Convert.ToDateTime(dtUploadedDate) + "," + dtForce + "," + dtPrinciple + "," + dtPrinciple + "," + NewTotal.Text);

const string sqlStatement =
                "INSERT INTO DEL_PurchasesLines1 (DealerCode,InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,ItemIdentityCode,PurchasingPrice,DiscountRate,Discount,IssueMode,Qty,Total,ExpireDate,BatchNumber,UploadedStatus,InsertedDate,UploadedDate,Force,Principle,NewTotal) VALUES"(yourstringCollection);
```

One more thing here you are fetching only controls not their values to fetch values from control use `.Text` .

```
 var dtExpireDate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("ExpiaryDate").text;
```

Answer (score 0):

pass ur nvarchar value to this method..

```
public static DateTime DateParse(string date)
        {
            date = date.Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            return DateTime.Parse(date, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));
            return new DateTime();
        }
```