# How can I convert string to datetime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I convert the following:

`031413 05:53 AM` into DATETIME format?

Where this code:

`SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '031413 05:53 AM')` gives me an error.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135746/sql-server-convert-string-to-datetime

Comment: The best solution is usually to avoid having a datetime in a string in the first place. If you keep datetime values in datetime types throughout your code, you don't tend to run into these sort of issues.

Comment: Are you retrieving `031413 05:53 AM` from somewhere?

Comment: yes, from a sql cursor using sql variable

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(50) ='031613 05:39 AM'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(@var,5,2)+LEFT(@var,2)+SUBSTRING(@var,3,2)+SUBSTRING(@var,7,9))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15788)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @a varchar(40) = '031413 05:53 AM'
select convert(datetime, right(stuff(@a, 7, 0, left(@a, 4)), 15), 109)
```

Result:

```
2013-03-14 05:53:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('031413 05:53 AM', 5, 2)
                         + LEFT('031413 05:53 AM',2)
                         + SUBSTRING('031413 05:53 AM', 3, 2)) 
FROM DATES
```