# SQL SERVER 2008 Filter between two dates and two times

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I  have a DateTime column called “Date_Entered”  and I need to filter between two dates and within these two dates to filter between two times (time might be of the next day). Here is my query:

```
Declare @StartDate DateTime 
Declare @EndDate DateTime 
Declare @StartTime varchar(8) 
Declare @EndTime varchar(8)

SELECT Date_Entered FROM MyTable
WHERE (Date_Entered BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/1/2015')
AND (CONVERT(varchar(8), Date_Entered, 108) >= '21:00:00' OR @StartTime IS NULL)
AND (CONVERT(varchar(8), Date_Entered, 108) <= '03:00:00' OR @EndTime IS NULL) --This time value is on the next day to cover a 6-hour period
```

The desired results should display all values that are within the date range (for 2014 year) and took place during the 6-hour range (night time):

```
2014-05-15 21:09:00
2014-08-12 02:45:00
2014-09-05 01:40:00
```

All the above happened during a date range (2014) and between the time of 9PM and 3AM on the next day.
My problem is that I need to search for time that happens from 9PM and 3AM on the next day (for the same date range)

If I search for time range in the same day like from 21:00 to 23:59 I get the results, but when time goes over the next day then I won't get any result.
Any idea how to do that in SQL.

SSRS 2012 is used to enter the value for the parameters.

The Date_Entered field is DateTime type that has date and a time.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear why you have `@StartDate` with a time component and then a separate time component as well.

Comment: time field also contains date ?? or its just like 1,2,3.. 24 ??? it it is like that then it will not make any difference today's date and tomorrow's date

Comment: I edited my question to provide sample data. The Date_Entered field is DateTime type that captures date and time.

Comment: A time can't both be >21:00 and <03:00.  You need to combine Date and Time into DateTime or change your query to account for the date.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV is correct.  Just change final and to OR of what you already had

Comment: @DiscipleMichael i think one bracket issue will be there , i did not execute it

Comment: try this SELECT Date_Entered FROM MyTable WHERE (Date_Entered BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/1/2015')AND (CONVERT(varchar(8), Date_Entered, 108) >= '21:00:00' OR (at)StartTime IS NULL) or(CONVERT(varchar(8), Date_Entered, 108) <= '03:00:00' OR (at)EndTime IS NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly then the below code will give correct output

```
create table a
(enddate datetime
)
insert into a values ('2014-05-15 21:09:00')
insert into a values ('2014-08-12 02:45:00')
insert into a values ('2014-09-05 01:40:00')
```

Query

```
SELECT enddate FROM a
WHERE (enddate BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/1/2015')
AND (CONVERT(varchar(8), enddate, 108) >= '21:00:00' )
or (CONVERT(varchar(8), enddate, 108) <= '03:00:00' )
```

Result

```
May, 15 2014 21:09:00
August, 12 2014 02:45:00
September, 05 2014 01:40:00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to convert the separate date and time fields into a single datetime field? Here's a link to a relevant SO question that provides an option for you to convert your search criteria into a single field. By doing so, it should let you to search for times beyond midnight within a single query.

[SQL Server convert string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135746/sql-server-convert-string-to-datetime)

Comment: It is a single DateTime field.

Comment: His StartDate and Endate fields are to limit the days that he searches, not to indicate the timespan to search for on each day.  In his post he's searching in a timespan everyday from 2014.