# Error when I set parameters to PreparedStatement

Tags: java, prepared-statement, mssql-jdbc

I have MSSQL procedure:

```
my_proc
```

I get data from java

```
String sql = "exec my_proc '2016-01-01','2016-01-20','2016-01-01'";
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

and get all data fine!

but if I use

```
String msisdn, String startDate, String endDate

String sql = "exec my_proc ?,?,?";
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, msisdn);
        stmt.setString(2, startDate);
        stmt.setString(3, endDate);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

I get error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type varchar to datetime.
```

In procedure I have variables:

```
@Startdtin datetime,
@Enddtin datetime,
@msisdnin varchar(18)
```

I tried use

```
stmt.setTimestamp(2, startDate); //startDate - convert to Timestamp
```

and

```
 stmt.setDate(2, startDate); //startDate - convert to Date (sql and util)
```

It is not helped. How pass date to `PreparedStatement`correctly`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error converting data type varchar to datetime. when I tried stmt.executeQuery()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358772/error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-datetime-when-i-tried-stmt-executequery)

Comment: Does this `startDate` is of type `String`?

Comment: This question is more correct. old deleted

Comment: What is `startDate` ?

Comment: @Satya yes startDate  is String wjth date for example '2016-01-01'

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135746/sql-server-convert-string-to-datetime

Comment: @ DwB in what place my question is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Your `startDate` is of type `String`. So convert it into `Date` type.

```
java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date(startDate);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());

-------------------------------
stmt.setDate(5, sqlDate);
```

Use `CallableStatement` to execute procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Once corrected the format of your data you have to change the code.

To execute a procedure you need to use a `CallableStatement`, not a `PreparedStatement`.

If you have your date in string format, first convert it to Date in java using a SimpleDateFormat.

Than simply set it as Date on the callableStatement.

```
String dateString = ...;
Date date = ...;

myCallableStatement.setDate(1, date);
```

Comment: why String sql = "exec my_proc '2016-01-01','2016-01-20','2016-01-01'";
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = stmt.executeQuery(); work fine?

Comment: It depends from the type of database and the type of procedure. Procedures can accept parameters for both input and output (generally parameters named in the calls as IN or OUT). If your procedure doesn't use the parameters for output it should works also with a PreparedStatement, otherwise is not possible to take the results. Generaly is a best practice to use a CallableStatement when executing procedures and use a PreparedStatement only when executing standard queries