# Find SQL Server query for order by date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, casting

My database is SQL Server, and the thing is that "dates" are stored as a string type. If I execute that query it does not order properly.

What I want to do is, get each day's value for between 7am and 8 am. For example, I want to get 14th of June records for between 7am an

Comment: If you want to order by date, you'll have to convert it to date. One of many reasons why you should never, ever store dates as strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server convert string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135746/sql-server-convert-string-to-datetime)

Comment: If it looks like a `DATE`, smells like a `DATE`, quacks like a `DATE` - ***why on earth*** aren't you storing it as  `DATE` ?? ***ALWAYS*** use the **most appropriate** datatype - don't just store everything as a string ....

Answer (score 1):

Use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` in your `WHERE` / `ORDER BY` clause conditions. 
However, you should store dates as date types instead of strings to avoid such problems.