# Parse DateTime from the string using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How to convert below string to datetime in sqlserver
'19-MAR-2018 12:00'

Comment: Select try_convert(datetime,'19-MAR-2018 12:00')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server convert string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135746/sql-server-convert-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CAST` to take string to a `DATETIME`

```
SELECT CAST('19-MAR-2018 12:00' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use convert:

```
select convert(datetime, '19-MAR-2018 12:00', 100)
```