# Convert 10JAN2000:00:00:00 to DATETIME in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been provided with a file whereby the dates are in the aforementioned format.

I have never seen this format before so am I going to have to separate the data out and convert each section or is this actually a known format?

Cheers

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most databases have some sort of `to_date()` or `parse_date()` functionality . . . except SQL Server.

If you are using SQL Server, then this should work:

```
select cast(stuff('10JAN2000:00:00:00', 10, 1, ' ') as datetime)
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, that works great - could you please elaborate on how this works - I'm not a man who likes to just cut and paste the solution, I'd like to understand how its the solution if you could please. Many Thanks.

Comment: @Lynchie . . . It simply replaces the first `:` with a space so SQL Server can convert the value.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by others, knowing which database changes the answer. SQL Server isn't keen on supporting date parse function unlike oracle, please read through below threads, might help with better understanding-

[Sql Server string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

[to_date in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569998/to-date-in-sql-server-2005/15121053#15121053)

In oracle of course, we can do something like this-

select to_date('10JAN2000:00:00:00', 'ddmonyyyy:hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

or

select to_timestamp('10JAN2000:00:00:00', 'ddmonyyyy:hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

Comment: Are you sure the `dual` table exists on his/her database system?

Comment: If its oracle then it must be, else its gives the idea how to convert into date format, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(to_date('10JAN2000:00:00:00', 'ddmonyyyy:hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd : hh:mm:ss') from dual;
```