# str_to_date function in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-to-datetime

MySQL has a function called [STR_TO_DATE, that converts a string to date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

### Question:

Is there a similar function in SQL Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to parse a particular format, use `CONVERT(datetime, @mystring, @format)`.  Use this as a reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20200729210252/http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Some examples:

```sql
SELECT convert(datetime, '10/23/2016', 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy

SELECT convert(datetime, '2016.10.23', 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd ANSI date with century

SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy

SELECT convert(datetime, '23.10.2016', 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy

SELECT convert(datetime, '23-10-2016', 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy

-- mon types are nondeterministic conversions, dependent on language setting

SELECT convert(datetime, '23 OCT 2016', 106) -- dd mon yyyy

SELECT convert(datetime, 'Oct 23, 2016', 107) -- mon dd, yyyy

-- 2016-10-23 00:00:00.000

SELECT convert(datetime, '20:10:44', 108) -- hh:mm:ss

-- 1900-01-01 20:10:44.000
```

Answer (score 7):

> What if the string is 7/7/2010?

Then use CONVERT with either 101 (mm/dd/yy) or 103 (dd/mm/yy) depending on what you want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '7/7/2010', 103)
```

Result:

```
2010-07-07
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CAST(<string> AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: can u give an example of how to use it? what is the string is 7/7/2010 as opposed to 07/07/10 ??

Comment: CAST/CONVERT works if you have a supported format - [STR_TO_DATE supports custom formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: STR_TO_DATE is mysql, not sqlserver

Answer (score 2):

Use [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
declare @MyString varchar(10)
declare @MyDate datetime

set @MyString = '2010-08-19'
set @MyDate = cast(@MyString as datetime)
select @MyDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example:

```
declare @myDate datetime
set @myDate = '06/09/2017'

select concat(convert(varchar(20), @myDate,101), ' -- ', 
              convert(varchar(20), @myDate,103), ' -- ',
              convert(varchar(20), @myDate,6))
```

This is what you get, depending on `101` or `103` or `6`:

`09/06/2017 -- 06/09/2017 -- 06 Sep 17`

A good summary of types of dates is here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score -1):

On MSSQL:
select cast('2012/06/12 10:32AM' as datetime);

You will get it:
2012-06-12 10:32:00.000