# CONVERT issue in sqlserver with Msg 529 error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
select CONVERT(datetime,value,103) from results
```

This statement is giving me a error

```
"Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Explicit conversion from data type text to datetime is not allowed."
```

VALUE column Datatype is TEXT in the RESULTS table.

How can i overcome the above problem. please help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't convert from `text` to `datetime`

You must apply two convert operations.

The first: From text to varchar

The second: From varchar to datetime

So your query will become:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,
       CONVERT(varchar(30),value), 103)
FROM results
```

Plus: `text` datatype is deprecated for new versions of Sql Server, so I strongly advice you to change (if you can) your datatype `text` into `varchar(max)`.

The DDL code to apply your change is:

```
ALTER TABLE results ALTER COLUMN value varchar(max)
```

Comment: When i used the above query, i am getting a error "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Please post the format of your date. I've used 103 as in your question you have written

Answer (score 2):

You need first to convert `text` to `nvarchar`. Try:

```
select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(30),value), 103) from results
```

Remarks: See [How to convert text column to datetime in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661737/how-to-convert-text-column-to-datetime-in-sql)

Comment: When i used the above query, i am getting a error "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 0):

To convert `text` to `float`:

```
CONVERT (float, CONVERT (varchar(20), text_column))
```