# Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Explicit conversion from data type int to time is not allowed

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    Reference_Number,
    c.First_Name + ' ' + c.Last_Name AS 'Customer_Name',
    Staff_FirstName + ' ' + Staff_LastName AS 'Staff_Name',   
    Date_Time, Summary, OtherDetails,
    CAST(Hold_Time AS TIME(0)) AS 'HoldTime',
    CAST(Duration AS TIME(0)) AS 'Duration',
    Call_Status         
FROM
    Support_Call AS tc 
INNER JOIN 
    customer AS c ON c.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
    staff AS s ON tc.StaffID = s.StaffID
WHERE 
    Call_Status LIKE 'Pending%'
ORDER BY 
    Date_Time DESC;
```

I'm trying to calculate all details of calls that are pending but I'm getting an error. `Reference_number` is of `INT` data type

Comment: What do `Hold_Time` and `Duration` represent? What data is in there? Did you mean instead to perform something like `CONVERT(time(0), DATEADD(second, Hold_Time, 0))`? Show us a few sample rows of the output of those two columns **without** the `CAST` and what you actually wanted/expected to see **with** the `CAST`.

Comment: please share some data of duration field from your actual table

Comment: _customer AS c ON c.CustomerID = c.CustomerID_  Well that is wrong.

Comment: We need to know the column type for Hold_Time and Duration.  Then look at other messages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831971/convert-issue-in-sqlserver-with-msg-529-error   which might point you to the answer, depending on column type of your inputs.

Comment: @smor I fixed that thanks but i'm still getting the above mentioned error

Comment: Note that the `time` data type isn't really appropriate for storing something called "duration". `time` represents a *time of day*, not a *time span*. Those are two separate (but of course related) concepts. `time` cannot store negative values, nor values greater than 24 hours; nor can you add two `time` values together. All of those things would make sense for time spans. None of them make sense for a time of day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Duration] (and/or [Hold_Time])  is of INT type, if the value is in minutes ([otherwise change accordingly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)), then use:

```
CAST(DATEADD(mi, Duration, CAST(0 AS DATETIME)) as time(0)) AS 'Duration'
```

Since you use TIME(0) data type, value of field after casting can't be greater than 24h

Answer (score 0):

May be this help?

```
Declare @Datum varchar(10)='3:00:00 PM'

--Convert it into Hour as integer 
Select  (cast (  SUBSTRING(@Datum, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @Datum, 1)-1)     as numeric (10,2))  +Cast ( (SUBSTRING(@Datum,(CHARINDEX(':', @Datum, 1)+1),2)) as numeric (10,2))/60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it guys thank you so much

```
SELECT Reference_Number,
       First_Name+' '+Last_Name AS 'Customer_Name',
       Staff_FirstName+' '+Staff_LastName AS 'Staff_Name',    
       Date_Time,Summary, OtherDetails,
       Call_Status      
FROM Support_Call AS tc INNER JOIN customer AS c
    ON c.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN staff AS s
        ON tc.StaffID =s.StaffID
WHERE Call_Status LIKE 'Pending%'
ORDER BY Date_Time DESC;
```