# Convert text into SQL date format

Tags: mysql, date, text

How can i convert a table containing date in text format into date format which can be used for sorting when exported to a spread sheet.

The first date format is "1/1/2017 12:00:01 AM" which needs to be converted to "01-01-17 12:00:01 AM" to be in date format not text which can be sorted on spread sheet and the type of the column is Text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661737/how-to-convert-text-column-to-datetime-in-sql this ask your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert text column to datetime in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661737/how-to-convert-text-column-to-datetime-in-sql)

Comment: is the table you are talking about in a database?  or a spreadsheet?  "The first date format is" ...is there more than one date format?  "12:01:01 AM" is not suitable for sorting.  maybe show the code that is putting the data in the spreadsheet?