# Simple DateTime sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How do I query DateTime database field within a certain range?

I am using SQL SERVER 2005

Error code below

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLENAME 
 WHERE DateTime >= 12/04/2011 12:00:00 AM 
   AND DateTime <= 25/05/2011 3:53:04 AM
```

Note that I need to get rows within a certain time range.  Example, 10 mins time range.

Currently SQL return with Incorrect syntax near '12'."

Comment: clyc's answer is correct: you need to add quotes. I've made this mistake before, because if you do `where date = 1/12/2011` for example, it will *appear* to work, but actually divide 1/12/2011 and get zero, and then treat zero as the minimum possible datetime value.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You missed single quote sign:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE DateTime >= '12/04/2011 12:00:00 AM' AND DateTime <= '25/05/2011 3:53:04 AM'
```

Also, it is recommended to use ISO8601 format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnn[ Z ], as this one will not depend on your server's local culture.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE 
    DateTime >= '2011-04-12T00:00:00.000' AND 
    DateTime <= '2011-05-25T03:53:04.000'
```

Comment: Does not work as well
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: @overule - try using the second example

Comment: @overule - also, make sure that your column has datetime type.

Comment: @Eric - yyyymmdd doesn't have time.

Answer (score 10):

You need quotes around the string you're trying to pass off as a date, and you can also use BETWEEN here:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM TABLENAME
  WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '04/12/2011 12:00:00 AM' AND '05/25/2011 3:53:04 AM'
```

See answer to the following question for examples on how to explicitly convert strings to dates while specifying the format:

[Sql Server string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Same error as above.

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

I am really confused.

Comment: oh, I just copied your date time, you've got 25/05 but it's probably expecting month/date so switch those both around.  I edited my answer and linked to a good question here on SO that shows how to convert strings to dates explicitly

Answer (score 9):

This has worked for me in both SQL Server 2005 and 2008:

```
SELECT * from TABLE
WHERE FIELDNAME > {ts '2013-02-01 15:00:00.001'}
  AND FIELDNAME < {ts '2013-08-05 00:00:00.000'}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can execute below code

```
SELECT Time FROM [TableName] where DATEPART(YYYY,[Time])='2018' and DATEPART(MM,[Time])='06' and DATEPART(DD,[Time])='14
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLENAME 
 WHERE [DateTime] >= '2011-04-12 12:00:00 AM'
   AND [DateTime] <= '2011-05-25 3:35:04 AM'
```

If this doesn't work, please script out your table and post it here. this will help us get you the correct answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already said that date literals in SQL Server require being surrounded with single quotes, but I wanted to add that you can solve your month/day mixup problem two ways (that is, the problem where 25 is seen as the month and 5 the day) :

1. Use an explicit `Convert(datetime, 'datevalue', style)` where style is one of the numeric style codes, see [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The style parameter isn't just for converting dates to strings but also for determining how strings are parsed to dates.
2. Use a region-independent format for dates stored as strings. The one I use is 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss', or consider ISO format, `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`. Based on experimentation, there are NO other language-invariant format string. (Though I think you can include time zone at the end, see the above link).

Answer (score 1):

```
select getdate()

O/P
----
2011-05-25 17:29:44.763

select convert(varchar(30),getdate(),131) >= '12/04/2011 12:00:00 AM'

O/P
---
22/06/1432  5:29:44:763PM
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have a type of datetime and you want to check between dates only ,,,use cast to select between two dates ....

example...

... where cast( Datetime as date) >= cast( Datetime as date) AND cast( Datetime as date) <= cast( Datetime as date)

Comment: How does this answer the question? Also, does this question need yet another answer?

Comment: if you have a type of datetime and you want to check between dates only