# How to get a specific time on a specific day SQL query

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm looking to do something similar to [Simple DateTime sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119369/simple-datetime-sql-query) but with a difference: I want to specify the time (7.00 am) on today's date.

I want to count the number of records that match the criteria at that time:

```
SELECT COUNT(SEQNO)    
FROM TABLE    
WHERE [CRITERIA]     
and [datetimecolumn] between (datetime=[today's date]at 7.00am)
and (datetime=[today's date]at 10.00am)
```

I can do it with date alone, but the time bit has me confused.

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, something you didn't specify.

Comment: Sorry, SQL2008 R2, query by HTML using webmatrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 Declare @i date=getdate()
Declare @j varchar(10)='07:00' 
Declare @k varchar(10)= '10:00:00' 

select COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT SOH.SEQNO),0) from dbo.SALESORD_HDR SOH 
inner join SALESORDHIST SOHIS on SOH.SEQNO = SOHIS.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ 
where SOHIS.HISTDATETIME between ( DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @i), @j)
and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @i), @k))
and SOHIS.EVENT_TYPE = 'I'
```

Comment: Hmmm.Entire query:    `select COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT SOH.SEQNO),0) 
from dbo.SALESORD_HDR SOH inner join SALESORDHIST SOHIS on SOH.SEQNO = SOHIS.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ 
where SOHIS.HISTDATETIME between (Declare @i date=getdate()Declare @j varchar(10)='07:00' select DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @i), @j)) and (datetime = date("Y/m/d"). ' 10:00:00')
and SOHIS.EVENT_TYPE = 'I'` which returns error near declare.

Comment: I re-arranged this and it works fine. Thanks to you all! @Eric T : my system didn't like `curdate` or `concat` - although I understood what you were suggesting. Turned out this `Declare` trick was the key.

Comment: Great, glad that you found the way : )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you as I assume 7am and 10am would remain the same as it is.

============================================

**BETWEEN** syntax should be something like this

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
    -> WHERE daily_typing_pages BETWEEN 170 AND 300;
```

[Credited to this site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm)

So your code should be: (Please include the brackets for the  datetimecolumn)

```
and ([datetimecolumn] between CONCAT( CURDATE(),  " 07:00:00" )
and CONCAT( CURDATE() ,  " 10:00:00" )
```

Comment: This looked promising, but it falls over saying 'incorrect syntax near "=" ' and "incorrect column name 'datetime'"

Comment: Maybe i was confusing in my OP. where i wrote `datetime=`, i am not sure what the correct thing to put here is.

Comment: Hi please read the edited answer above and reply if it still return in syntax error.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'date' is not a recognized built-in function name. I inserted the entire query string below

Comment: Hi there are you doing php mysql?

Comment: Sorry, SQL2008 R2, query by HTML using webmatrix. cshtml file that queries the sql directly.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.