# How do i write a code for the previous date?

Tags: sql, date, time

```
date ,                         rate
1/2/2014 12:15:00.0000 PM,     abc
8/2/2014 12:15:00.0000 PM,     efg
etc...
```

let say i have data that are updated once a week,for example:1/2/2014 is the update date, and the second week will be 8/2/2014 etc...
condition: i want to write a code in sql,if the client choose the day in 4/2/2014 and it will choose to show the data in 1/2/2014.

i have tried the query more or less like this:

```
SELECT rate,date FROM mytable WHERE year(date)=2014 AND month(date)=2 AND day(date)=4
```

but it give me empty data since there is no data at 4/2/2014 and i want the query can show the data from the previous date which is 1/2/2014

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119369/simple-datetime-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.* from table t where
t.date between dateadd(dd,-7,t.date) and dateadd(dd,7,t.date)
```

would translate to

```
select t.* from table where 
4/2/2014 between 3/26/2014 and 4/9/2014
```

does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the database you are using or the data types.  Let me assume that the data types are, indeed, dates.  The following query gives the idea:

```
SELECT rate, date
FROM mytable
WHERE date <= '2014-02-04'
ORDER BY date desc
LIMIT 1;
```

The above gives guidance.  The syntax for the date constant might vary among databases.  And, the `limit 1` is not supported by all databases, so this might be `top 1` or `where rownum = 1` or `fetch first 1 rows` or perhaps even something else.

Comment: thank you for reply, i want to declare only date, but the data includes time portion, what is the solution?

Comment: @user3413288 . . . First, I'm not sure if this makes a difference for your application.  second, date operations are quite database specific, so there is no generic method.