# String replace '05/12/2011 17:04:00' to Cast('05/12/2011 17:04:00' As DateTime)

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

I have a scenario whereby the hosting provider will only provide a backup SQL script of a MSSQL database. This results in DateTime values being scripted as '05/12/2011 17:04:00'.

Hence the error,

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Does anyone know a way whereby I could find all DateTime values and wrap them with Cast(... As DateTime)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it working

```
select cast('05/12/2011 17:04:00' as DateTime)
```

Comment: Only if the value of month and date values goes out of range then it will show that error. Since Sql Server will accept date in this format `mm/dd/yyyy` rather than this it will show that error

Comment: See here i have given this value `select cast('14/20/2011 17:04:00' as DateTime)` and the error shown is `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: There are many INSERT statements where is this happening. Is there a way to mass update the INSERT statements? Or am I approaching this from the wrong direction?