# SQL convert 'DDMMYY' to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a date from `DDMMYY` format to `datetime` in SQL Server.

I am using the `convert` command as follows

```
select convert (datetime, '311012', <style>)
```

I have tried looking on msdn for the supported styles but haven't found an exact match.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you have a _string_, representing a date, which is formatted as `DDMMYY`?

Comment: A very nice Explanation:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Yes I have a string with no spaces in DDMMYY format. For eg - '311012'

Comment: If this is a string literal, How did you know whether `YY` is `20yy` or `19yy`? in your example is it `2012` or `1912`?

Comment: @Pranav I did look at that explanation as well as the MSDN page - but there is no example for my exact format DDMMYY

Comment: In my example it is 2012 - that is provided in the source file specifications

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select convert (datetime,  Stuff(Stuff('311012',5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'), 4)
```

Comment: "Stuff" inserst a string in another sting. In this example, "Stuff" is used twice to insert two periods (at index 5 (fist) and 3 (last)). Thus transforming "311012" to "31.10.12" which is a datetime format (4) that convert can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
declare  @val1 varchar(30)
select @val1=SUBSTRING('311012',1 ,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING('311012',3 ,2)+'/'+'20'+SUBSTRING('311012',5 ,2)
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,@val1,103)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select CAST('121031' AS datetime)  as d -- For YYMMDD
```