# How to convert XML string value to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, datetime

I have below code which selects a date value from an XML string in SQL Server. The string value returns format in `ddmmyy` and I need to convert this to T-SQL `datetime` type before saving it to a table.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    list.n.value('(DOB/@value)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'DOB'
FROM 
    @ResultXML.nodes('/Variables') AS list(n)
```

XML file:

```
<Variables>
    <DOB>111290</DOB>
</Variables>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert varchar into datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: That answer is for another format `mmddyy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try it like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
'<Variables>
    <DOB>111290</DOB>
</Variables>';

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(@XML.value('(/Variables/DOB)[1]','varchar(max)'),3,0,'/'),6,0,'/'),3)
```

First you use two times `STUFF` to get `11/12/90` instead of `111290`, than you use the `3` to convert this to datetime (or any other fitting format: use `.` for german, `-` for british...) [More details on `CAST and CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Best was, to store date and time values properly. Within XML this should be ISO8601, which means `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` [More details on ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer from following link similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512238/475709

Answer (score 0):

If SQL 2012+

The example

```
Declare @String varchar(25)= '111290'
-- If MMDDYY
Select DATEFROMPARTS(iif(Right(90,2)>25,'19'+Right(90,2),'20'+Right(90,2)),Left(@String,2),Substring(@String,3,2))

-- If DDMMYY
Select DATEFROMPARTS(iif(Right(90,2)>25,'19'+Right(90,2),'20'+Right(90,2)),Substring(@String,3,2),Left(@String,2))

Returns:  1990-11-12
Returns:  1990-12-11
```