# Integer to datetime t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to convert int to date format, The values are in this format `ddmmyy`
    280118

`select cast( '280118' as date)`  this results in `2028-01-18`,

I have found way from Stack using substring

```
select convert(date, SUBSTRING('280118',1,2)+'/'+
         SUBSTRING('280118',3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING('280118',5,2),3)
```

Expected Result `2018-01-28`. 
Is there any simple alternate way to acheive this in `SQL server 2016`, It is also quite useful if you can suggest from version `2012` onwards.

I have seen posts as this has been answered already many times, i would like to see any simpler ways of answering this.

Appreciate your comments, suggestions

Comment: are they all from the 21st century? Easier way would be to store dates as dates.

Comment: The secret to these questions is to google for the mask: *t-sql "ddmmyy" to datetime*

Comment: I dont think we go beyong 20th century, but i am really looking for a simple solution. This data stored in staging in this format, so would like to store it in correct format in actual table @scsimon

Comment: Did we learn nothing from Y2K? Is it possible to fix the source of this data to use 4 digit years?

Comment: Well, I was more so interested if there were any 19XX years. I suspect there would be, and that's going to be fun for you to work with. I agree with @SeanLange though, naturally

Comment: I think this is similar to the question answered here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512019/sql-convert-ddmmyy-to-datetime?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) by @bummi

Comment: @SeanLange Source cant not be alterted, Source column comes as Schemenumber(ex01)+ddmmyy+mmss+Storenumber, I am modifying traditional strign type of workign approach to align correct data types

Comment: @Michael I am looking for a simple answer to `select convert (datetime,  Stuff(Stuff('311012',5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'), 4)` as you have suggested in the link

Comment: Cant understand why question gets downvote as it is clear and concise, i would appreciate any comments made to improve question or out of topic

Comment: Well somebody should go smack however decided to go back to 2 digit years.

Comment: Seems that downvoting is an epidemic around here. People like to downvote a lot. Not really sure why.

Comment: @SeanLange If i ask Business managers or IT Team how data is handled in the past ,the answer i get `it is what it is`  :)

Comment: Then tell them GIGO (Garbage In, Garbage Out). :)

Comment: @SeanLange I believe it doesnt motive to post questions, but i have seen knowledge base in stack with SQL i  am ok with it

Comment: I agree. It is a demotivator for people to ask questions. Sure there are plenty of repeats and those with no research. Yours has certainly been answered before but you did at least attempt to solve it on your own. Hardly seems downvote worthy to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL convert 'DDMMYY' to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512019/sql-convert-ddmmyy-to-datetime)

Comment: That is not an integer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stuff here and the format option of convert to do this fairly easily. This of course makes the assumption that ALL dates will use the default century. In a couple decades this will no longer get the correct decade unless MS changes their default logic for centuries with 2 digit years.

```
declare @YourDate varchar(10) = '280118'

select convert(date, stuff(stuff(@YourDate, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/'), 3)
```

Comment: Appreciate this answer, i have used this answer in my comments. I guess there is no other way round than using stuff/substring .Like `FORMAT`?

Comment: There are plenty of alternatives but none as simple that I am aware of.

Comment: `Format` returns a string, not converting from string to another data type

Comment: @ZoharPeled I guess there is no other ways, the only reason i have asked this question if any new functions added to the newer versions.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I would be happier if some other users make an effort to find an alternative solution rather commenting, or marking duplicate.

Comment: Side note: If you are only ever going to work with dates in this century, change the outer stuff to insert `/20` instead of `/`, and convert using 103 style. That way, you don't have to worry about possible 20th century dates: `select convert(date, stuff(stuff(@YourDate, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/20'), 103)`