# selecting data between 2 dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am Working in ASP.NET and SqlServer.

I have two textboxes with **calender extender** in my application where user will select two dates.I want to get data between those two dates from sqlserver where my datatype for that particular field is **DateTime**. please tell me how to proceed with this ...I wrote a query but thats not working..

my query:

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 OrderNumber from tblOrderMaster where OrderedDate>='" + txtfromcal.Text + "' and OrderedDate<='" + txttocal.Text + "' ", conn);
```

Comment: whats the problem? any error or exception...

Comment: The answers here might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Don't use text representation for dates. Convert the input to `DateTime` first and then use that for the comparison. Also, don't build your queries like that; use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
Sqlcommand cmd=new sql command ("Select data from tablename 
                                where date>=startdate 
                                and date<=enddate",connection)
```

Answer (score 8):

things to do

- parameterized the query to prevent from sql injection
- use `using` statement to properly dispose the object
- use `try-catch` block to handle excpetion

eg,

```
string query = @"select top 1 OrderNumber 
                from tblOrderMaster 
                where OrderedDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString here"))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", txtfromcal.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", txttocal.Text);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            // other codes
            // to fetch the record
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with 
            // e.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

SOURCES

- [AddWithValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Add (*recommended method to be used*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE  sqlDateColumnName  BETWEEN  '" + textbox1.Text + "' AND '" + textbox2.Text + "'