# SQL Server 2008 - convert varchar to datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a `varchar` column (`dateandtime`) with date and time in the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and I need to convert it to a `datetime` column.

I have a temp column `dateandtimetemp` in the table .

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '15/05/2013 13:55:12', 104)
```

It should return : `2013-05-15 13:55:12.000`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),113) ;
```

it return result in following format

15 May 2013 16:26:29:850

Answer (score 1):

So then just go ahead and try it!

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET DateAndTimeTemp = CAST(DateAndTime AS DATETIME)
```

and see if it works. If your input data is really always properly defined - you should have no issues here.

This of course depends on what langauge/dateformat setting you have activated in your database - so that might be the first problem you encounter.

If you do have issues, then you can always "clean up" your input data and try again ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/05/2013 11:12:13', 103)
```