# converting to date time with only date and hour passed in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server, i want to insert datetime into my datetime column. The parameters i recieved as follows

```
@hour int,
@date varchar(10) -- format YYYY-MM-DD
```

How do I convert to this datetime format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

MM will be 00 as we only consider the hour.
HH:MM will be in 24 hours format

Example :

```
@date = '2014-10-2'
@hour = '8'
```

Should be converted to

```
2014-10-2 08:00:00
```

How do I do this?

Comment: [Not a duplicate, but should be interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Don't you mean that you want this result? `2014-10-02 08:00:00`

Comment: Also, you might want to clarify whether `@hour` is supposed to be an `int` or a `varchar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider that both the variables are of varchar type since you enclosed both the variables with quotes

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @date + ' ' + convert(varchar(10),@hour) + ':00:00')
```

Comment: Okay but i kept on getting `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-10-20 ' to data type int.`

Comment: @edward use `CONVERT(VARCHAR, @hour)`

Comment: @MadSorcerer - varchar inside convert without size is not a good practice. Try to mention the size

Answer (score 0):

here is one another way to do this:-

```
declare @hour int=8,
@date varchar(10)='2014-10-2'
select dateadd(hh,@hour,CONVERT(datetime,@date))
```