# Convert SQL date varchar(512) to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date, string-to-datetime

When I want to "translate" a Ndate figure into dd/MM/yyyy I use this

```
convert(varchar(16),dateadd(day, d.Field_Date, '01-01-1970'),103)
```

But I have a field that's VARCHAR(512) with that very format, and I'd like to convert that string to a date format.

Could you (yes, you :-)) tell me how to do it in SQL Server language?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the same query:

```
declare @date varchar(512) = '03/11/2015'

Select CONVERT(date, @date, 103)
```

103 is the correct style to use with `Convert` for British/French dates (dd/mm/yyyy)

Output as date:

```
2015-11-03
```