# TSQL: How to swap characters in a string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I've stored a date as a string in a test DB and the text was stored with the mm and dd swapped.  I have a lot of records and I would like to automate this if possible.  Is there a way in SQL to swap characters based on the position?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE #D (
DateAsString varchar (10)
)

INSERT INTO #D (DateAsString)

VALUES 
('20160601'),
('20160127'),
('20160129')

SELECT 
DataAsString

FROM #D
```

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the SUBSTRING function

Comment: Thanks @AntDC, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (DateAsString VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MyTable (DateAsString)
VALUES ('20160601')
    ,('20162701')
    ,('20162901')

SELECT DateAsString
    ,substring(DateAsString, 1, 4) + substring(DateAsString, 7, 2) + + substring(DateAsString, 5, 2) AS DesiredResultAsString
    ,Convert(DATE, substring(DateAsString, 1, 4) + substring(DateAsString, 7, 2) + + substring(DateAsString, 5, 2)) AS DesiredResultAsDate
FROM @MyTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
Update #D 
    SET SwapDateAsString = FORMAT(CAST(Dateasstring as DATE), 'yyyyddMM')
```

**Result**

```
DateAsString    SwapDateAsString
20160601        20160106
20160127        20162701
20160129        20162901
```

Comment: Thanks @KrishnrajRana.

Comment: Nice Solution but you are assuming that he is using SQL 2012 or newer.

Comment: @MarkKram: OP have added tag of `SQL Server 2014` in his question. So my solution perfectly worked.

Answer (score 2):

Since SQL Server [does not allow arbitrarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion) string to date/time parsing (like TryParse or Parse in .NET), you must construct your dates from pieces:

```
declare @dateStr VARCHAR(8) = '20162701'
select DATEFROMPARTS(substring(@dateStr, 1, 4), substring(@dateStr, 7, 2), substring(@dateStr, 5, 2))
```

Comment: actually you should only concat substrings in different order,  OP doesn't ask to convert such stirng as `DATE`

Comment: Yes, but it is strongly recommended to store the date as DATE or at least DATETIME2, not as VARCHAR. Since he takes the time to make this correction, I expect to try to do it fully.

Comment: Agreed, nonetheless I always recommend using native/built in functions.

Answer (score 1):

I found a function at this [LINK](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) called fnFormatDate and since you didn't state which version of SQL Server your were using this solution should work for all versions of SQL from 2005 and newer. BTW I will be adding to my ETL Functions Library. Here is my solution:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.fnFormatDate', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.fnFormatDate
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnFormatDate (@Datetime DATETIME, @FormatMask VARCHAR(32))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @StringDate VARCHAR(32)
        SET @StringDate = @FormatMask
        IF (CHARINDEX ('YYYY',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'YYYY',
                                DATENAME(YY, @Datetime))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('YY',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'YY',
                                RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, @Datetime),2))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('Month',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'Month',
                                DATENAME(MM, @Datetime))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('MON',@StringDate COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)>0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'MON',
                                LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime)),3))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('Mon',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'Mon',
                                            LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime),3))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('MM',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'MM',
                        RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)),2))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('M',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'M',
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('DD',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'DD',
                                RIGHT('0'+DATENAME(DD, @Datetime),2))
        IF (CHARINDEX ('D',@StringDate) > 0)
            SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'D',
                                            DATENAME(DD, @Datetime))   
        RETURN @StringDate
    END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Tempdb..#D', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #D

CREATE TABLE #D(DateAsString varchar (10))
GO

INSERT INTO #D (DateAsString)
    VALUES 
            ('20160601')
            ,('20160127')
            ,('20160129')
            ,('20160229')
            ,('20161231')
    GO

SELECT 
    DateAsString
    ,NewDateAsString = dbo.fnFormatDate(dbo.fnFormatDate(DateAsString, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYDDMM') 
 FROM #D
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MarkKram!   (My tag had 2014, but I'll but that in my title or in my question moving forward.)  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(8) = '20160601'
SELECT  @d as BasdDate, SUBSTRING(@d, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(@d, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(@d, 5, 2) as GoodDate
```