# SQL Server : convert string to numeric - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a dataset in SQL Server Management Studio.

The data looks like the following

```
month   Year
-------------
Feb     2016
Jan     2015
```

I want to create a numeric date using 01 as dd. I tried

```
CAST('01-'+ month +'-'+ year AS DATE)
```

also

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-'+ month +'-'+ year, 106) AS
```

Both of them cause this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can anyone teach me how to covert the string into numeric datetime/date please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Now that you have a solution you should consider changing your datatype to store date information in the proper datatypes. In this case probably date. Storing this as strings is full of challenges that are just not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the reason is the hyphens.  You should try with spaces instead:

```
convert(datetime, '01 '+ month +' '+ year, 106)
```

Another possibility is that `month` contains invalid values.  In SQL Server 2012+, use `try_convert()` to avoid that problem:

```
try_convert(datetime, '01 '+ month +' '+ year, 106)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use concat with convert if 2012+

```
Select convert(datetime, concat(1,month ,year), 106)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `CONCAT` is new in SQL Server **2012**, so if the OP uses an earlier version, he won't be able to use this

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
convert(datetime, concat('01-', mnth , '-',yr), 106) AS d
```

Comment: It should be noted that `CONCAT` is new in SQL Server **2012**, so if the OP uses an earlier version, he won't be able to use this