# SQL: How to get the date yyyy/mm/dd based on the year and day number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following string 2015089 or 2016075, for example.

I need to get the result in `yyyy/mm/dd` format based on the given input.

So, based on 2015089, I get, `2015/mm/dd`. dd is a 89th day of 2015 and mm is a month that has 89th day.

How can I do something like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/207232/507793

Comment: Is Jan 1 represented as "1" or "0"?

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest way is to convert to a date using `dateadd()`:

```
select dateadd(day, right(str, 3) - 1, datefromparts(left(str, 4) + 0, 1, 1) )
```

That is, add one less than the number of days to the beginning of the year.  This assumes that Jan 1 is represented as "1" and not "0".

You can then format the date however you like.

In pre-SQL Server 2012, you can do:

```
select dateadd(day, right(str, 3) - 1, cast(left(str, 4) + '0101' as date))
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. But as a disclaimer, it's valid for SQL Server 2012+.