# Convert dd/mm/yyyy to date in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, date, varchar, sql-convert

I'm going nuts trying to convert a string type column into date.

The column name is `StartDate`, which contains a string date format `dd/mm/yyyy`. The field type is `varchar(3000)`.

I tried the following:

```
CONVERT(datetime, StartDate, 103)

CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartDate, 110) AS DATE)

CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(StartDate, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(StartDate, 4, 2) + '-' + LEFT(StartDate, 2), 126)
```

and other similar combinations.

I keep getting "out of range" and "conversion failed" error messages.

Does anyone have a creative solution?

Comment: then you have bad data (something like `30/02/2015` or `12/13/2017`, etc)

Comment: The first and the third variant should work just fine. The second one (with style 110) is for another format: mm-dd-yyyy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: **John Cappelletti** you were right! I have many records where StartDate = 00/00/0000. I will use iif function to change it into null.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @inbal_bpr Try_Convert() will return a NULL value if the conversion fails

Comment: John Cappelletti 

try_convert(date, StartDate, 103) returns '1900-01-01' where StartDate is null..

Comment: @inbal_bpr That is expected.  I now understand your IIF() statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have some bogus data.  For example

```
 Select try_convert(date, '15/07/2014', 103)
```

Returns

```
2014-07-15
```

If 2012+, I would suggest that you

```
Select *
 From YourTable
 Where try_convert(date, StartDate, 103) is null
```

This will identify your problem areas