# Use TO_DATE in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a problem. When I execute this SQL statement in SQL Server 2012:

```
TO_DATE('2011-11-09 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

I get an error:

> 'TO_DATE' not is a name de function integrate recognized.

What is the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Not duplicate, my format date is diferent.

Comment: Questions don't need to be exact duplicates as long as the answers still apply. We don't need one question for every possible format people could be using in `TO_DATE`.

Comment: SQL Server has moved on since that prior question

Comment: When format date is diferent, the solution can be diferent

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SQL-Server has no `TO_DATE`  function. You have to use `convert`.
See [here](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date)

```
-- Specify a datetime string and its exact format
SELECT TO_DATE('2012-06-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual;


-- Specify a datetime string and style 102 (ANSI format), raises an error if conversion fails
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-05', 102);

  -- TRY_CONVERT available since SQL Server 2012 (returns NULL if conversion fails)
  SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-05', 102);
```

For your specific case use:

```
convert(DATETIME, '2011-11-09 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 6):

TO_DATE() isn't a valid function in SQL Server (T-SQL)

The alternatives depend on what version of SQL Server you are using

[CAST() or CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) may be used in any version. Starting with SQL Server 2012 onward one can use [TRY_CAST()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) or [TRY_CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql). The advantage of using the latter pair is they do not error if the strings cannot be converted when they return null instead.

For date/time strings generally using CONVERT() or TRY_CONVERT() is used as you can pass ["style" numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) where YYYY-MM-DD is "style" 102 e.g.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE,'2017-01-21',102)
```

However it is possible to use CAST/TRY_CAST like this example:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;  
SELECT TRY_CAST('12/31/2016' AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CONVERT` In Sql Server Can Do The Same Job Of `TO_DATE` In Oracle

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, yourDate ,104)
```