# What is Oracle to_date function equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, oracle, date, sql-date-functions

How to convert this piece of code from Oracle to get the same behaviour in SQL Server ?

```
select to_date('20141008174025', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
from dual
```

Comment: Already asked and answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074493/use-to-date-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't an exact equivalent. `CONVERT()` only supports a limited catalogue of fixed [formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles).

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `datetimefromparts()`:

```
declare @str varchar(20) = '20141008174025';
select datetimefromparts(
    substring(@str, 1, 4), 
    substring(@str, 5, 2), 
    substring(@str, 7, 2), 
    substring(@str, 9, 2),
    substring(@str, 11, 2),
    substring(@str, 13, 2),
    0
)
```

You can also do:

```
declare @str varchar(20) = '20141008174025';
select cast(
    left(@str, 8) 
        + ' ' 
        + substring(@str, 9, 2) 
        + ':' 
        + substring(@str, 11, 2) 
        + ':' + substring(@str, 13, 2)
    as datetime    
)
```