# How to write a date concisely in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the employee table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
    id            integer        PRIMARY KEY,
    surname       character(15),
    employed_date date
);
```

to which I insert the following row:

```
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES (4, 'Smith', to_date('2015-11-28','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Can I instead simply write?

```
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES (4, 'Smith', '2015-11-28');
```

It works in my PostgreSQL installation. However, I would like to write portable code that works also in other databases, including Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL and SQLite; and with any locales.

Does it work also in these databases? If no, then maybe another format works in these databases and/or is ANSI standard?

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is the standard date format which is YYYY-MM-DD. However, all but trivial portable SQL code is almost impossible, especially for date handling. If you want to write portable code, use a SQL builder library.

Answer (score 2):

Most DBMSes (but not SQL Server & SQLite) support ANSI/Standard SQL *date literals* with a fixed `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```
date '2020-09-20'
```

Similar for time and timestamp:

```
time '12:34:56'
timestamp '2020-09-20 12:34:56.02'
```

Comment: I have found this literal format in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html), and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) documentations.
I cannot find it in SQL Server docs - maybe SQL Server has rather this literal: `{d '2015-11-28'}` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/date-time-and-timestamp-literals))?

Comment: I don't know the exact location in the manuals, but it's valid T-SQL since at least SS2014

Comment: Sorry, my fault, SQL Server still doesn't support it, Gordon is right. Same for SQLite

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using a `char()` type for the surname.  This type pads the name with spaces, which is generally unadvisable for names.  In general, you want a `varchar()` for names:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id            integer        PRIMARY KEY,
    surname       varchar(15),
    employed_date date
);
```

I should add that 15 characters is probably not long enough for last names.

Or perhaps `nvarchar()`.  The above works in all your mentioned databases, although Oracle recommends `varchar2()`.

As for date constants, there are basically two ways to insert them:

```
date '2020-11-03'
'2020-11-03'
```

The first is standard SQL, but not all databases support it.  Of the databases you mention, only Oracle requires the `date` keyword.  SQL Server and SQLite don't allow it.
The databases that do not allow `date` will convert the string to a date, if a date is expected.

So, there is no single way to pass in a date constant that works across the databases you have mentioned.  Well, the major exception is Oracle.  And you can change the default date format to accept YYYY-MM-DD rather than DD-MMM-RR, but that is rarely done.

Comment: 1. I was aware that `character(15)` type can be not well suited. I was migrating `VARCHAR2(15)` in tutorial database from Oracle to Postgres, and temporary chose it.
2. There is even no `to_date()` in SQL Server [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074493/use-to-date-in-sql-server-2012), which I used in Oracle and Postgres.

Comment: If there is no common constant format, then maybe there is some function common for Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL and Postgres; like [Cast or Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7175369/4592248)?

Comment: @iwis . . . That is even less likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sql statement below to add a new employee to employee table. With the date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

```
 INSERT INTO employee (id,name,date) VALUES (4, 'Smith', '2015-11-28')
```