# What is the alternative of string format in python

Tags: python, string, datetime, format

I have below python code as sql query to update a record in table:

```
query = "UPDATE mytable SET data='{}' where id='{}'".format(value, id)
```

This updated the record in table. Now I have another query which include datetime:

```
send_dt = datetime.utcnow()
query = "UPDATE mytable SET data='{}', send_datetime='{}' where id='{}'".format(value, send_dt, id)
```

Now because I have include `send_dt` inside format, it is making the type datetime to string and thus I am getting below error:

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

How can I update my query so that datetime remains datetime and not string. Thanks

Comment: Please do not use string formatting to prepare queries! This is vulnerable to malicious and erroneous input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use to_date function to convert into date format. Somthing like this.

```
send_dt = datetime.utcnow()
query = "UPDATE mytable SET data='{}', send_datetime=to_date('{}','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss.FF9') where id='{}'".format(value, str(send_dt), id)
```

or instead of calculating the date use the predefined function in the sql.

```
query = "UPDATE mytable SET data='{}', send_datetime=sysdate where id='{}'".format(value, id)
```

Comment: `'to_date' is not a recognized built-in function name`

Comment: to_date is valid function for oracle db. Which db you are using.

Comment: I am using azure sql

Comment: Use convert instead of timestamp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074493/use-to-date-in-sql-server-2012#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=CAST()%20or%20CONVERT(),when%20they%20return%20null%20instead.