# SQL Server date conversion from string value

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

In my table, I have a string-represented date column in the following format: `{^2013/05/29}`.

How do I convert this to standard `datetime` format in SQL Server? This contains string characters that are not part of what a datetime string usually has.

Comment: With [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and then a cast to `Date` or `DateTime` or `DateTime2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: I found the problem. It is right here. "I have a string-represented date column". https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That format is recognizable as a strict format by VFP only. Is that stored in SQL Server as text? If so:

```
Select cast(substring(myColumn, 3, 10) as date) as myDate from myTable;
```

would do the conversion.

If you mean it is stored like that in a VFP table and you want to convert a date then:

```
select ctod(myColumn) as myDate from myTable;
```

Comment: Ah... VFP, my first true love.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, everyone who have seen and used VFP loved it:) Unfortunately one day it was acquired by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('^2018/05/29','^','') AS DATETIME2)
```

Comment: You also need to remove { and }.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is **always** in the format `{^yyyy/MM/dd}` then you could use:

```
CONVERT(date,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(YourDateColumn,3,10),'/',''))
```

Ideally, however, you should be fixing your column to be the correct datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (DateColumn varchar(13));
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('{^2013/05/29}');
GO

SELECT *
FROM Test;

UPDATE Test
SET DateColumn = CONVERT(date,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(DateColumn,3,10),'/',''));

SELECT *
FROM Test;

ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN DateColumn date;

SELECT *
FROM Test;
GO

DROP TABLE Test;
```