# How to convert string to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, sql-server-2016

I have done my share in converting string to date in SQL Server 2016 but never seen a date with the format like the one below. I have looked online for a possible way to convert it without success. Any help helping me converting the string below to `datetime` datatype in SQL will be appreciated.

```
Fri Aug 24 2018 22:28:40
```

Regards,

Comment: What database engine and version?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016

Comment: I'm not sure that SQL Server can directly convert your datetime string.

Comment: Do not use logic in SQL... Delegate it to your Bussines Logic language... ASP? .NET? C#?

Comment: I am not familiar with any of those languages. I usually build all my logic in SQL

Comment: Usually logic and presentation formating goes into whatever client-side language you happen to use and are familiar with. Leave the DB engine the raw datetime for which it's optimized.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing timestamps as strings to begin with

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it in SQL Server:

```
select cast(right("string",20) as datetime) as dateColumn
from table
```

Comment: Just to mention this: Be aware of the language dependency. "Aug" would work in many cases, but "Dec" was "Dez" in my culture... This might work in many cases and still breaks on another system.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with non-standard date formats, I usually lookup `CONVERT` function in SQL Server, as it io very "elastic": you can provide various formats to it, so it recognizes them appropriately.

I use [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) for reference. There you can find, that the closest date format is indicated by 100:

```
0   100    mon dd yyyy hh:miAM/PM    Default
```

It's your format except it doesn't include unnecessary in this case day of week information. So all you need to do is cut out the `Fri` part:

```
substring(myDatetimestring, 5, 1000)
```

or even better

```
substring(myDatetimeString, charindex(' ', myDatetimeString), 1000)
```

if the day of week part may have variable length. Don't worry about `1000`, it only assures that we will have the rest of the string, not any less.

Now we have proper date format, since it says that it's default, we don't need to supply `100` to `convert` function and also we can use `cast` function instead, as you discovered, so we could do:

```
cast(substring(myDatetimeString, charindex(' ', myDatetimeString), 1000) as datetime)
```

or

```
convert(datetime, substring(myDatetimeString, charindex(' ', myDatetimeString), 1000), 100)
```

or

```
convert(datetime, substring(myDatetimeString, charindex(' ', myDatetimeString), 1000))
```