# Need to get the date part from a column and Convert the time zone from UTC to CST time zone

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to get the date part from column Start_DateTime (varchar data type) which is having data like '06/04/19 10:44 AM CDT' , '06/10/19 11:56 AM EDT' and need to convert the time zone to CST time zone

I have a user defined function `dbo.fn_UTCtoCST` that will convert the time zone but am trying to combine all this in a select query to get the desired result

```
SELECT 
            Start_DateTime
           ,Inspector
           ,Status
           ,Distance
           ,Location
from XYZ
```

Comment: Never store timestamp values in a `varchar` column. The problem you have now, is a direct  result of using the wrong data type

Comment: You may refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 0):

If your function is scalar value function(returning one value) then this might will work for you.

```
select * 
from A 
  cross apply dbo.fn_UTCtoCST(date)  cstdate.
```

Comment: Why the apply? If the function is a scalar function you can use it directly in the SELECT list: `select dbo.fn_UTCtoCST(date) from a`

Comment: I meant to say function should return one row(one value).

Comment: There is a huge difference between "one row with one column" and a "single (scalar) value"

Comment: One row one column that means single value i guess.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/898089/how-to-create-scalar-value-function-in-sql-server-2012/