# Convert string to datetime - SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-date-functions, sql-convert

I have a string parsed from XML which represents datetime.
String format is:  '20200915114000' - (YYYYMMDDhhmmss)

Is there a function in SQL Server to convert or parse this string to datetime or should I split string manually and concatenate it into datetime?

Comment: which database are you using postgres or mysql?

Comment: asked earlier, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: I'm using Microsoft sql-server

Answer (score 0):

How to do this, in 3 steps:

```
C:\> SQLCMD
1> select convert(datetime,'20200915114000' )
2> go
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Server ZES, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
1> select convert(datetime,'20200915 114000' )
2> go
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Server ZES, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
1> select convert(datetime,'20200915 11:40:00' )
2> go

-----------------------
2020-09-15 11:40:00.000

(1 rows affected)
1>
```

Conclusion you need to add a space and 3 ':' in the string to convert `'20200915114000'` to `'20200915 11:40:00'`. After this a simple CONVERT will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, yes im getting all the time "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." or other error

This is OK now, I thought that there is some other approach

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem:

```
declare @sDate char(14), @sDateOK char(20)

set @sDate = '20200915114000'    
set @sDateOK = substring(@sDate,1,8) + ' ' + substring(@sDate,9,2) + ':' +  substring(@sDate,11,2) + ':' +  substring(@sDate,13,2)

select convert(datetime,@sDateOK ) as Date
```

Comment: `select convert(datetime,format(20200915114000,"00000000 00:00:00"))` will do it too, This way it is even possible to do `select convert(datetime,format(20200915114000,"0000-00-00 00:00:00"))` with  the result `2020-09-15 11:40:00.000`.