# SQL string to datetime

Tags: sql, hue

I have a colum that is showing a date as a string. It comes through as '07/01/2021 01:03:47 AM' I am trying to query so that I can pull all data where the date is greater than '07/01/2021 01:03:47 AM'.

I have tried select * from datatable
where date> '07/01/2021 01:03:47 AM'

I also tried select * from datatable
where cast(coldate as timestamp)> '07/01/2021 00:00:00'

but because it is a string it won't pull the correct view. I will show a random collection of data due to the string.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the specific type of SQL you're working with.

Comment: ..store the value as a date instead of a string.

Comment: Troubleshooting tip:  Try `SELECT cast(coldate as timestamp) FROM datatable` .   Does that explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql Server string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: when I use SELECT cast(coldate as timestamp) FROM datatable the date comes back as date field comes back as null.

Comment: Date functions are very specific to the RDBMS.  Which one are you using?

Comment: You might be able to get away with something like this, but you will need to provide the appropriate format strings for ```TO_DATE``` and ```TO_CHAR```  - ```to_char(to_date(date_field,'yyyymmdd'),'dd-Mon-yyyy')```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cast('7/1/2021' as datetime)
```

and

```
Convert(varchar(30),'7/1/2021',102)
```

See [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187928(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more details.