# I am getting an error when converting a varchar column into a date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.

I have a table with a column called [DateReceived]. Now the column is a 'varchar' column. The date format is: '18/05/2022'. When I try to convert it to a 'date' column using:

```
ALTER TABLE Correspondence ALTER COLUMN [DateReceived] DATE;
```

I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

Comment: Could you please tell what is unclear in this message? You can take a look on TRY_CAST-function to see what "varchar"-dates can not be converted to date

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy isn't an automatically recognised date format in SQL Server, so the system can't just directly convert it into a datetime without some help. You need to explicitly convert it first by specifying the input format, as per the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply convert a text date column to a bona fide date in this way.  What you could do would be to create a new column and populate it using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Correspondence ADD DateReceivedNew Date;
```

Then, populate it using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```sql
UPDATE Correspondence
SET DateReceivedNew = TRY_CONVERT(date, DateReceived, 103);
-- note: use format mask 103 for dd/mm/yyyy
```

In the case of any error, your `DateReceived` column may have bad data in it.  You may use the following query with `TRY_CONVERT` to flush out any offending records:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Correspondence
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, DateReceived, 103) IS NULL;
```

Finally, you may drop the original `DateReceived` column, and rename `DateReceivedNew`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Correspondence DROP COLUMN DateReceived;
sp_rename 'Correspondence.DateReceivedNew', 'DateReceived', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It is very well explained. So far I have tried the first two steps and the column converted successfully.

Comment: One thing I noticed now is that after following the 1st two steps. The data came out in yyyy-mm-dd format. Initially it was a varchar with the dates in the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: @WaliBadawi Dates in SQL Server do not have any internal format.  If you want to view your dates a certain way, then maybe use the `FORMAT()` function to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `DATEFORMAT` to `dmy` first.

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN d date;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0088871b979f09dce305617c57602215)

Comment: Thanks, it does work however is there a way to get it in the UK format. dd/mm/yyyy ? like in the example above.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, `dmy` is UK format, as shown in the fiddle

Comment: I noticed that also but when I tried it the dates come out in the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding: dates stored as `datetime` don't have a format, they are binary. What you see is just how the client displays it. A good client should be able to format it to text in a variety of formats. If you want to format it  into text in SQL when you query it (as opposed to how you store it), you can use `CONVERT` with a style parameter https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3cc95bee43752b57139e425784cce079 Note that this same issue will happen with the other answer