# SQL date comparison

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do I check if the timestamp date of a record is before midnight today?

datediff is driving me nuts...

Comment: If today was the 2008-11-21, do you mean everything up to and including 2008-11-21 23:59, or 2008-11-21 00:00?  Most of the answers so far presume the later.  In which case you can just add a day to those results.

Comment: Add 1 Day and subtract 4ms. IIRC SQL handles datetime to the nearest 3rd of a millisecond. So 2008-11-21 23:59:59.997 would get "rounded" into 2008-11-22 00:00:00.000. Its caused a few bugs in some reporting software I was maintaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to get 0 hour of today in SQL

```
SELECT (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() as FLOAT)) AS DateTime))
```

Just compare your time against that.

Don't use varchar casts since they are slow.

[Check this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202243/custom-datetime-formatting-in-sql-server#202288)  for more date time help.

Comment: I find the datediff-dateadd method preferable, as shown by @CadeRoux

Comment: I'd be curious to know if there is a performance difference between them.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
WHERE dtColumn < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where myColumn < cast( (cast(getdate() - 0.5 as int)) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the datatype of the column you ate using is "TimeStamp", not dateTime or smalldatetime ?

If so, then you're out of luck.  This datatype has nothing to do with dates or times (it's really misleading...)  It's just guaranteed to be chronologically unique and sequential... But there's no way ot compare it with a datetime

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(SQL.80).aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/timestamps-vs-datetime-data-types

Answer (score 0):

If ColumnName (column you are examining) is of datatype datetime, and NOT timestamp,
then the fastest approach is

```
Select Case DateDiff(day, columnName, getDate()) 
   When 0 Then 'Today' Else 'Earlier' End
From TableName
```

assuming all dates values in ColumnName are now or earlier...

Easiest way to think of datediff is that it counts the number of "boundarys" of the specified type that you have to pass over to get from one datetime to another...