# Ignoring Time stamp for a count in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime-format

I am having an issue figuring out what I thought would be a simple query.
I have a table with two fields (EntryDateTime, Message) that as you can guess logs specific messages with a time date stamp for a monitoring app.

I am looking to get a count of all messages of a type per day but the time part of the stamp (while needed for everything else) giving me issues here.

I was looking to do something like,

```
SELECT COUNT(Message)
FROM DBName.dbo.TableName
WHERE Message = 'LoginFailed'
GROUP BY EntryDateTime
```

What I am looking for as the output is something like

> 2009-06-26, 142
>
> 2009-06-27, 259
>
> 2009-06-28, 57

Of course this is giving me an output of messages more like

> 2009-06-26 00:01:01, 11
>
> 2009-06026 00:01:02, 12

Any help getting ride of the timestamp for this query would be very helpful. I would like to not have to manually enter any date ranges as this query will be searching a years worth of logging and I would love to not enter 365 date ranges for a `BETWEEN` type query.

Comment: To properly display code like T-SQL or C# or VB.NET, please highlight the lines in question and then use the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard. This will nicely format the code and provide syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks marc_s. I will make sure to use that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT (Message), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), EntryDateTime, 101))  
FROM DBName.dbo.TableName  
WHERE Message = 'LoginFailed'  
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), EntryDateTime, 101))
```

Comment: Conversion to string isn't the fastest method.  https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: Very true.  If this is going to be a huge table/result set, you'd want to try something different

Comment: This worked great. There are a number of these messages in this table I am looking for, but it is in the 20-30K range and this was very fast.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(d, 0, Getdate()), 0)
```

Replace Getdate() with your Column Name.

You'll also want to look at this previous [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202243/custom-date-time-formatting-in-sql-server/202288#202288) and also this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493223/sql-drop-time-in-datetime)

Comment: This one gave me the dates I needed but I was still having issues getting the count right. However, I have been looking into this and think I can use it else where.

Thanks