# How do I check if the current time is between two times in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

This isn't working:

```
IF EXISTS (( SELECT  1
            FROM    dbo.SalesOrder )
   AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '16:00:00'))
   BEGIN
         PRINT 'yes!'
   END
```

I want to do:

If something exists in the `SalesOrder` table AND the current time is between 7am and 4pm, then print 'YES'

I'm assuming I might have to do a conversion there but I'm unsure on how to do it properly.

Anyone care to give me a hand?

Comment: I fixed it. All I'm trying to do is 1. check if someone exists in table A and 2. if the current time is between 7am and 4pm. 1 and 2 are completely different things.

Comment: @Ben Did someone figure out this is for SQLServer?  Or is this still generic/should work on all DBs?

Comment: tsql tag usually indicates sql server...

Comment: @samyi ah ok, I guess no one uses Sybase anymore...

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT top 1 'yes'
FROM    dbo.SalesOrder
WHERE datepart(hour, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 7 and 16
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faec5/4)

Comment: Doesn't `GETDATE()` return a datetime? You're comparing it to two strings. How will that work?

Comment: This isn't working, unfortunately.

Comment: convert(time,getdate()) needed?

Comment: `TIME(GETDATE())` ?  Although that may just work on MySQL.

Comment: Time after 1600 hours will also be considered here, so this will match from 7:00:00 to 16:59:59

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to compare datetimes for the same day, you will need to remove the time component of GETDATE(), then add X hours. There are a few other conversions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202288/16391).

```
IF EXISTS (( SELECT  1
            FROM    dbo.SalesOrder )
   AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN 
                      DATEADD(hh,7,(CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() as FLOAT)) AS DateTime))) AND DATEADD(hh,16,(CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() as FLOAT)) AS DateTime)))))
   BEGIN
         PRINT 'yes!'
   END
```

Comment: Can you say `CAST(GETDATE() as TIME)`?

Comment: Dunno, have used the CAST/FLOOR/CAST for a while because it has always been the faster method. Your approach may be as good or better (its a heck of a lot shorter). Any idea if it is?

Comment: I couldn't get an actual compare of two SQL Server `TIME` objects to work unfortunately.  Even MSDN recommends turning them into float.

Comment: I don't have a use the TIME data type as of yet. Everything still in DATETIME/DATETIME2 for me.