# Remove seconds from datetime

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have query as below:

```
select  
 lower(convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101) +
 ' '+ 
 substring(convert(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 22),9,Len(GETDATE())))
```

**In this query i am getting result as:**

```
06/27/2014   6:23:57 pm
```

I just want to remove seconds (i.e. 57) from above.

My intentded result is:

```
06/27/2014   6:23 pm
```

How can i obtain it??

I tried adding Length in the query as:

```
select  
 lower(convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101) +
 ' '+ 
 substring(convert(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 22),9,Len(GETDATE())+1))
```

But it didnt help.

Plase help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below

```
 SELECT CAST(DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)+'/'
+CAST(DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
+'/'+CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
+' '+CAST(DATEPART(HH,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
+':'+CAST(DATEPART(MI,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
```

also look at this [Custom Date/Time formatting in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202243/custom-date-time-formatting-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
select  
lower(convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101) +
' '+ 
LEFT((substring(convert(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 22),9,Len(GETDATE())+1)), 6)
+
(RIGHT(substring(convert(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 22),9,Len(GETDATE())+1),2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @date datetime

select @date = GetDate()

select convert(nvarchar, @date, 101) + ' ' + right(convert(nvarchar, @date, 100), 6)
```